# Is parameter for controller method with name Message forbidden?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application with feedback form which is processing by FeedbackController.

```
 @model ClientMessageDto
 ...
 ...    
    <form class="contact-form form-horizontal" asp-action="Enrol" asp-controller="Feedback" asp-anti-forgery="true">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Message"></label>
                    <textarea asp-for="Message" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">
                                Send request
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And I have a controller method which should receive DTO from my form

```
Route("enrol")]
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Enrol([FromForm]ClientMessageDto message)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {area = ""});
    }

    return View(clientMessage);
}
```

This method always receives object with empty fields even if I use [FromForm] attribute.
But it works if I change parameter name to whatever except message (something like messageDto or clientMessage works properly).

Is it ok and 'message' word is forbidden or I should report it as a bug?

Comment: The problem is likely that you have a form value also called `Message` and that is conflicting.

Comment: Does `[Bind("Name,Email,Phone,Message")]ClientMessageDto message` help ?

Comment: @DavidG You are right. It seems like both messages are conflicting. Renaming one of them could solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a bug with MVC, it simply due to the conflict between the `message` parameter that your action method is taking and the `Message` form field. That's confusing the default model binder. You could probably write your own custom model binder, but as you've already figured out, it's a lot easier to rename either the action method parameter or the form field.